# Accessing multiple Laravel model's data through a query and displaying

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-4, eloquent

**Logic**

> A company has many users. Each user has many alerts. Each alert
>   belongs to one location.

I want to display each user's alerts, and the alert's respective location, in a table. Preferably with the user's name at the side of each alert.

The company and user is linked through a pivotTable, a belongsToMany relationship.
The alert belongsTo a location.
The location hasMany alerts.

Alert model:

```
public function location()

    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Location');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
```

User model:

```
public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Company')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function alerts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Alert');
    }
```

Company model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Location model:

```
public function alerts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Alert');
}
```

So far, I have this within the controller:

```
public function getAdminIndex()
{   
    $company_id = User::find(Auth::user()->id)
        ->companies()
        ->first()
        ->id;
    $alerts = Company::with('users.alerts.location')
        ->where('id', '=', $company_id)
        ->get();
    $this->layout->content = View::make('agents.admin.index',
         array('alerts' => $alerts));
}
```

**How I interpret the query**

1. Get the company ID of the authenticated user.
2. Get each user that belongs to that company, along with any alerts they may have and their respective location.

Going over to the view, the MYSQL queries that have been executed seem to be correct, however, I cannot for the life of me print out the data, say for instance, in each alert.

I imaging the query would be something along the lines of (based on the models):

```
@foreach($alerts as $alert)
    <td>{{$alert->users->alerts->location->address_1}}</td>
@endforeach
```

But each time I am presented with one error or another - the most common one is `Trying to get property of non-object`.

Any help would be hugely appreciated on how I can display each user's alert and their respective location.

Comment: can you show us a model that is being retrieved by the query ?

Comment: Your problem is that you can't distinguish which relation/query returns Collection and which returns a single Model. Because of that you try to get related alert or location of a bunch of users/alerts (Collection) which is obviously impossible.

Comment: What would you suggest Deczo to alleviate this problem? As I'm not sure what you're saying sorry!

Comment: @seblaze Models added.

Comment: I hope the answer I gave will make it clear for you why you get those errors and how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in the comment as may be seen in your previous questions: You must learn what is returned from the queries (Collection of models or Model) and how dynamic properties (loading relations) works.
To make it perfectly clear for you, a little guidance first:

```
// Company model
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User')->withTimestamps();
}

// now you can do this:
$company = Company::find($someId);

$company->users;
// which does behind the scenes:
$company->users()->get();
// thus returned Collection
```

---

```
// Alert model
public function location()
{
  return $this->hasOne('Location');
}

// calling relation:
$alert = Alert::find($id);

$alert->location; // single model because it does the same as:
$alert->location()->first();
```

---

That being said, you may access related models like this:

```
$company->users->first()->alerts->first()->location->address_1;

// and for your needs use of course loops:

// don't call it $alerts as it returns company with some relations
$company = Company::with('users.alerts.location')
    ->where('id', '=', $company_id)
    ->first(); // use first not get for the reason I mentioned above

  @foreach ($company->users as $user)
    @foreach ($user->alerts as $alert)
      {{ $alert->location->address_1 }}
      ...
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
```

---

Trashed alerts:

```
// User model
// additional relation for ease of use
public function deletedAlerts()
{
   return $this->hasMany('Alert')->onlyTrashed();
}

// only change in the call is replacing alerts with deletedAlerts:
$company = Company::with('users.deletedAlerts.location')
    ->where('id', '=', $company_id)
    ->first();

@foreach ($company->users as $user)
  @foreach ($user->deletedAlerts as $alert)
    {{ $alert->location->address_1 }}
     ...
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Deczo, thank you so much. You explain it better than the Laravel documentation itself. I owe you one. Many thanks.

Comment: Just as another quick ask, sorry, if I wanted to retrieve the exact same information, but this time, the  deleted `alerts` (soft Delete), this query would have to change completely, correct?

Comment: You're like a Laravel encyclopedia. Seriously. Thank you Deczo, again. I'm sure it won't be the last time you hear from me... ;)

Comment: Hi Deczo, sorry to be a pain, the code presents no errors, but it returns the same live alerts as in the original code above. I have checked and there should only be two deleted ones, but all the live ones still display?

Comment: The MYSQL query I can see being executed is `select * from alerts` where `alerts`.`deleted_at` is not null and `alerts`.`user_id` in ('2', '7', '17', '18', '1', '21') if that helps.

Comment: You have to use deletedAlerts in the foreach loop too :) Otherwise you simply call the 'alerts' relation for every user (which by the way causes n+1 queries issue)

Comment: It works, perfect. If you wasn't over in Poland I'd buy you a beer.

Answer (score 0):

As log as your models have the correct relationship methods, I think that all your missing in your query (and hence the object error) is first(). Like this:

```
@foreach($alerts as $alert)

    <td>{{$alert->users->alerts->first()->location()->address_1}}</td>

@endforeach
```

Comment: I have added my models. The code above also returns this error: `ErrorException
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$alerts`

Comment: Please try it with the updated echo line as I added the brackets. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you don't want the database calls in your controller but in your model to stay true to the MVC paradigm. I'm trying to wrap my head around this. I think you can restructure this to just relations and call everything inside your foreach loop.

```
@foreach($user->company()->users as $company_user)
<tr>
   <td>
   {{ $company_user->username }}
   </td>
   <td>
   @foreach($company_user->alerts() as $alert)
      {{ $alert->message }} - {{ $alert->location()->name }}
   @endforeach
   </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

With this setup and the right relations this should work out. It's a complicated structure. The pitfall is that the amount of alerts is probably variable (can be 0 or more right)? So you have to do this in one `<td>`. Hope you will get it done! Let us know if it worked out or made progression!

Comment: completely agree with the database calls in the controller. Understanding your logic would mean, each user has one location, the location is related to the alert. Each alert has one location. I have attached my models.

Comment: This is one heavy setup! ;)

Comment: Logically, it all makes sense to me! But it's displaying all of the information which is proving a right headache!

Comment: Could you specify exactly what you want to do? Because it's hard to see from the models relations. Maybe write out some pseudo code. Like divide your step 2 in more steps. :)

Comment: Sorry sidneydobber, I ended up following Deczos answer. Thank you so much for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `$alert->users` is a collection and each `$user` has `$alerts` which is also another collection and you are trying to use a property from the collection, in this case, you need to loop all alerts:

<strike>@foreach($alerts as $alert)
        
            @foreach($alert->users->alerts as $alert1)
                {{ $alert1->location->address_1 }}
            @endforeach
        
    @endforeach</strike>

Actually, `$alert->users` is a collection so:

```
@foreach($alerts as $alert)
    @foreach($alert->users as $user)
        @foreach($user->alerts as $anAlert)
            {{ $anAlert->location->address_1 }}
        @endforeach               
    @endforeach       
@endforeach
```

Well, lets re-write the whole thing:

```
$companies = Company::with('users.alerts.location')
                    ->where('id', '=', $company_id)
                    ->get();
```

Now you have a collection of `Company` models with `users (collection)` and each `users` has another collection of `Alert` so multiple users and multiple alerts and then each `Alert` has one `Location`, so:

```
@foreach($companies as $company)
    // Each User belongs to multiple company, so multiple users here
    @foreach($company->users as $user)
        // Each User has multiple alerts
        @foreach($user->alerts as $anAlert)
            // Each location belongs to one alert
            {{ $anAlert->location->address_1 }}
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately it returns this error `ErrorException Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$alerts`

Comment: I've use `$alert1` later, did you notice that ?

Comment: I copied your code over entirely. The error of `$alerts` looks like is referring to the line above. `->users->alerts` part.

Comment: Sorry WereWolf, I ended up following Deczos answer. Thank you so much for your help though.